# Multiple letters to the same address

Tags: letters, letterhead

Is it possible to use from and to field to have same addresses, while the content of the text continue to change using a letter class. This will be useful in a case when someone has to send monthly reminders/ letters. To explain I include MWE

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
\\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}

I am writing to you on behalf of the Wikipedia project (http://www.wikipedia.org/),
an endeavour to build a fully-fledged multilingual encyclopaedia in an entirely
open manner, to ask for permission to use your copyrighted material.

% The \ldots command produces dots in a way that will not upset
% the typesetting of the document.
\ldots

That said, allow me to reiterate that your material will be used to the noble end of
providing a free collection of knowledge for everyone; naturally enough, only if you
agree. If that is the case, could you kindly fill in the attached form and post it
back to me? We shall greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I look forward to your reply.

\closing{Can I leave this field empty?}

\ps

P.S. You can find the full text of GFDL license at
\url{http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html}.

\encl{Copyright permission form}



%----------------------------------------------------
% Next week suppose I have to write letter to the  same person
\letteragain % I am aware that such command may not exist 
I am thankful to you for allowing me such a use 
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you maybe clarify your problem a bit more? I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Markus I want to write series of letters to same person.

Comment: it could be possible to simply use something like `\include{body_tex_file}`. You would compile the letter, but only change the text of that particular file containing the letter body.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to invest some time, then swap the letter class for scrlttr2 from the KOMA-script bundle. You'll probably get the manual by typing `texdoc komascript` on the command line. You layout your letterhead and save it in an *.lco file, for the address you'd simply make a newcommand.

You can start easily, if you download Lyx (www.lyx.org) and install it, because it comes with a template for KOMA-script letters. You could export the whole *.lyx file and swap the letter class options into a *.lco file and the rest into a template for your letters.

That said, the whole thing will take some time, because KOMA-script is a mighty beast and you'll have to learn how to ride it.

The advantage is that writing letters is much shorter and convenient afterwards.